# Android Firebase offline connections

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I have two questions can someone please help me with this:

1. How to enable Firebase cache offline data only at a few parts of the android app NOT THE ENTIRE APP.
2. How to enable Firebase cache offline only when the internet isn't connecting / not able to connect to the Firebase server else connect to the live real-time data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot cache only partial data, it's the entire database or nothing.
2. That's how it works. When a device losses connectivity, your users can continue using your app, as long as you have enabled offline persistence. And there is nothing that you should do, as it works autiomatically.